# Way to get back formatted Windows MBR partition in dual boot system

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, mbr

I have a Dual boot system and accidentally formatted Windows MBR partition while trying to format a USB (*via disks utility*). Now I am not able to boot into Windows.

My grub doesn't show Windows anymore. Is there a way I can get access to Windows ? I have tried boot recovery and it doesn't work.

Comment: You can, unless critical information has been deleted.  Some "fdisk" programs are better for this than others.  Some top contenders include OpenBSD's fdisk, or RPM (Ranish Partition Manager) for DOS.  They let you see and edit details much more precisely than some other software.  (I'm not saying that most people would consider their interfaces to be the most user-friendly.)  Don't give up, and be careful.  If the data is really important, than doing a full-disk ("forensic image"-style) backup, before making any changes, may save you from accidental destruction during repair attempts.

Comment: @TOOGAM can you correct or clarify what may be a typo in your first sentence. You write "You can, unless critical "  Do you mean you can't unless? that'd be more normal english. Or do you indeed mean you Can (restore it), unless critical information has been deleted. In which case it's better to say (restore it)  And what "critical information" are you talking about?

Comment: -1 Your question is a nonsense. MBR is not a partition so your title conflicts with what you wrote, and the question makes no sense.. Did you "delete the MBR", or did you delete the partition. And when you say you deleted the MBR.. what do you mean? What did you do exactly? I've heard of an MBR being changed, but not deleted. So maybe that is perhaps a nonsense too.

Comment: Clarification: "You can" get access to Windows again, if you fix things right.  f you have a bad partition table,  and you attempt to fix the problem by writing a new partition table, but your new one is bad, then you may easily overwrite important data in a filesystem, thereby deleting old data that could have been useful for recovery.

Comment: @barlop: Get up to speed.  After the advent of GPT, a phrase (which was possibly recently invented) started to become more widespread: an "MBR partition" is a partition that is specified in an MBR, as opposed to partition defined by a GPT (or a BSD disklabel).  The phrase "Windows MBR" in the title is unclear, but the question's "deleted windows MBR partition" is valid terminology using the newer definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in another castle!

Just gonna dump my recent solution to the SAME problem, as suggested by another user.

***Solution***

---

I HIGHLY recommend fixing the problem with a Super grub disk. I have had the same problems as you and this was what I used to fix it.

Next time you want to uninstall linux, just use this disk as it features an easy to use 'uninstall OS' option.

Download link; http://www.supergrubdisk.org/

:D

To set up a grub super disk, use Ubootnet, win32disk imager or some other disk imaging software, and create a bootable usb. Alternatively you can use a disk if you have some laying around.

Im guessing you should know this process since you did install linux.

Once inside of Super grub disk, a 'fix boot' menu should pop up. Use this, and make sure to look at settings like 'fix windows' and 'fix mbr'.

I would like to mention however, that if you cant boot in to ANY live USB, or any OS then you have serious problems. Under no circumstance should you motherboard bios boot stop working for the problem you have asked, and if this is the case, then the problem could be a lot worse then indicated.

Comment: If this tool does not work for you, but you can still boot into it, take a look at Gparted. Ask yourself some questions. Is the windows partition reasonable size? if so, then there should not be a problem.

Comment: Please don't use signatures at the bottom of your posts. From http://superuser.com/help/behavior: `Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.

Every post you make is already “signed” with your standard user card, which links directly back to your user page. If you use an additional signature or tagline, it will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.`

Comment: well, maybe that might help if he corrupted his MBR. But what you describe doesn't sound like it'd work for a deleted partition (see the contents of his question, and TOOGAM's comment)

Comment: There is a boot partition on legacy boot? If you delete it, this will fix it???? I dont see why your being uptight about the quesiton...
@Mokubai Sorry, didnt know that, will be sure to update signed answers